# Salesforce Continuous Integration : Only components in the same namespace as the organization can be created through the API

Tags: migration-tool, migration

I have a Salesforce CI newbie issue. I'm trying to build a CI pipeline for Salesforce using Bitbucket / Jenkins and the Salesforce Migration tool.  I'm trying to prototype the pipeline against a dev org using a source dump from sandbox which contains a number of licensed packages ( many of which are integrated into standard objects such as Account ). I'm encountering ( understandably enough ) the following error - 
"Only components in the same namespace as the organization can be created through the API"
Is there a best practice to deal with issues such as this ? Do I need to download and deploy all licensed managed packages ?

Answer (score 4):

You have to either remove the managed package items, or install the managed packages. You can use [InstalledPackage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_installedpackage.htm) to help automate the process if you want to go down the path of installing dependencies, or you can install them manually; Developer Edition orgs, like Sandbox orgs, can install any package and get an unlimited Site license for evaluation purposes. If installing is not suitable for your purposes, you'll want to come up with a way to strip any references to those packages from your code and metadata, which may be easier said than done.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion re. InstalledPackage. We really do need this to be fully automated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that when you're retrieving from the sandbox you're retrieving using a non-specific package.xml file.  As a result, when you retrieve the Account object, you get everything on Account including custom fields with namespaces from those installed packages.  When you take that metadata and deploy to another org, it's trying to create fields that are in a namespace you don't own hence the error.  You can get around this in one of two ways:

1. Use an Unmanaged Package in your Sandbox org to select the metadata you want to retrieve.  Go to Setup -> Create -> Packages and create a package.  You won't ever distribute this package from here, but a package is a useful container that you can add your custom metadata into.  Once you've added the metadata you want into the package, use the packageNames argument to the sf:retrieve call in your Ant targets.  Set the value of packageNames to the package you created in the org.  With this retrieve mode, you don't provide a package.xml file.  The retrieve returns only the metadata in the package.
2. Manually create a specific package.xml file for what you want.  For example, don't retrieve the whole Account CustomObject in your package.xml file.  Instead, just retrieve the CustomFields you want.  I'd recommend option 1 as this can get painful to maintain.

If your custom metadata references fields or other metadata from any of the installed packages, you'll still need to use InstalledPackage to automate the installation in your build scripts.

FWIW, I spent the last 3 years building out our CI process around Ant + Force.com Migration tool, Jenkins and Github.  From my experience, Ant can become a burden with more complex build automation logic like handling dependencies.  It's possible and I built [CumulusCI](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/CumulusCI) around Ant which I've been running for the last 3 years.  That inspired me to spend the last 6 months rewriting it all in Python as [CumulusCI 2.0](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/CumulusCI/tree/feature/2.0) version that's in alpha now.  Feel free to poke around for ideas for your scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; however I realized that wasn't my problem. I was able to resolve it by using installedPackage as suggested by sdfcfox. I'm facing a different issue while trying to install ( using the api ) npsp 3.0. This is what I see .

Comment: All Component Failures:
1.  installedPackages/npsp.installedPackage -- Error: (Contacts & Organizations 3.4) A required package is missing, Details: Package "Contacts &amp; Organizations", Version 3.4 or later must be install\
ed first.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue. The issue occured because of different format/type of component.

When we're deploying using MDAPI(from SFDX Command/Ant/Workbench etc.) it requires different format and with the advent of scratch org(or SFDX) folder structure, it uses different formatting of files(specially object files).

To resolve the issue - I used `sfdx force:source:convert` command to convert Scratch org compatible folder structure into MDAPI compatible folder structure.

Hence the issue resolved.